# Django - formset unique_together delete add

Tags: python, django, unique-constraint, django-forms

Let's consider these models

```
class Session(models.Model):
    staff = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Supplier')
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(_('start'))
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(_('end'))

class Participation(models.Model):
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session)
    atendee = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Attendee')
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('session', 'attendee')
```

I'm using an inline formset to manage the `Participations` into a `Session` editor.

Imagine the following scenario:

- I add a participation with an attendee
- Remove this participation (delete checkbox checked)
- Add it back with the same attendee (new line)

If I send this formset, I will get a contraint error

> A Participation with this Session and Attendee already exists.

Seems like the validation does not take deleted children into account.
Is it considered to be a normal behavior ?
In that case how can I properly manage this case ?

---

In order to reproduce this behavior, use the admin site with these admin classes:

```
class PartInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Participation

class SessionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PartInline]

admin.site.register(Session, SessionAdmin)
```

Comment: Can you post your view/url/form code (everything we need to reproduce and help) ? I think there should be a way to enforce deletes to happen before saves ... a way that can be found after a little hacking :)

Comment: To reproduce the behavior, simply use the admin with a default inline formset class (I have this same error with my urls/views/forms). I'm going to add it into the question